# How sobel operator mask matrix is created?

Tags: image-processing

http://www.cis.rit.edu/people/faculty/rhody/EdgeDetection.htm

This seems the only article tries to describe how the sobel operator comes from equation. But i am certainly not understanding the aspects.

In that page , they let

```
A = array of actual image , B = grayscale version

Horizontal gradient B(j ,k) = taking column values = A ( j,k+1 ) - A (j,k)
```

My question , why taking column values for horizontal ?

Then again , they said :

```
This can be represented by a filter array as shown below: as a matrix [-1,1]
```

How this filter array comes from that equation ? Also , i am having hard time to understand why [-1,1] becomes [-1,0,1] and then this horizontal and vertical matrices are not "multiplied" to get the sobel operator , they are product of 2-dimensional convolution operation. What the hack that means ?

Comment: 404 error for the article you mention..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a sample array, `A = [1,4,9,16,25]`.

We need to find horizontal derivative of this array as per the article you mentioned.

When we talk about horizontal derivative, we need to take difference between elements in a row. ie how a data varies in a row, ie horizontal derivative. Similarly variation of data in a column is vertical derivative.

First equation was : **`B[j,k] = A[j,k+1] - A[j,k]`**

=> `B[0,0] = A[0,1] - A[0,0]` => B[0,0] = 4-1 => 3

=> `B[0,1] = A[0,2] - A[0,1]` => B[0,1] = 9-4 => 5

=> `B[0,2] = A[0,3] - A[0,2]` => B[0,2] = 16-9 => 7

=> `B[0,3] = A[0,4] - A[0,3]` => B[0,3] = 25-16 => 9

So finally **`B = [3,5,7,9]`**

Applying above equation is same as convolving A with [-1,1].

Just for an example, `B[0,3] = -1xA[0,3] + 1xA[0,4]` => -1x16 + 1x25 => 9

---

Now we try with second equation : **`B[j,k] = A[j,k+1] - A[j,k-1]`**

=> `B[0,1] = A[0,2] - A[0,0]` => B[0,1] = 9-1 => 8

=> `B[0,2] = A[0,3] - A[0,1]` => B[0,2] = 16-4 => 12

=> `B[0,3] = A[0,4] - A[0,2]` => B[0,3] = 25-9 => 16

So finally, **`B = [8,12,16]`**

This operation is same as convolving A with [-1,0,1].

Just for an example, `B[0,3] = -1xA[0,4] + 0xA[0,3] + 1xA[0,2]` => -1x9 + 0x16 + 1x25 => 16

---

Similar is the case with vertical derivative also.

(If need more details, put comments.)

Comment: Man you are my hero ! All other places all i saw "this is some advanced stuff kid"

Comment: I wonder why **Sobel operator** is `[-1 0 1]`? Why don't we use `[-1 1]`?

Comment: Then it won't be sobel :). I don't know exact answer. I think it may be to remove the shift caused by [-1,1]. Not sure. I think sobel is used for 2D convolution.(check wikipedia). It applies a gaussian smoothing first to remove noises. It is better to have the size of kernel odd number, so that main pixel is anchored at center. Also check the frequency transform of two kernels to find any valuable ideas. I am afraid I don't know much.